# Facebook Chat XMPP protocols

Tags: facebook, xmpp

I read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/. Now I wonder if anyone knows a list of XMPP protocols which is usable on facebook xmpp server.

Another question is if it is possible to retrieve old chat messages via XEP-0013?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The link you give has a list of supported protocols.

It does not include XEP-0013.